# React Redux Toolkit: Naming convention between slice and store

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I hope that finally someone can answer my question ... which is more of a general "good to know" question rather than a vitally important one :-)

I cannot for the life of me find a definite answer to my question whether or not the `name` property of a Redux Toolkit slice has to correspond to the property name of the reducer in the configured store. None of the tutorials I read and viewed and even the docs show the connection between these ... it's just that EVERY single tutorial used the same name for both

Example:

counterSlice.js

```
export const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: "counter",
  initialState: { count: 0 }
  ...
});
```

store.js

```
import counterReducer from "../features/counter/counterSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    counter: counterReducer,            // does this "counter" have to be the same as the name in the slice?
  }
});
```

Component:

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const count = useSelector((state) => state.counter.count);   // and this "counter" also? If NOT, what is the connection?
```

Comment: No, the `name` property of the state slice doesn't correspond to the key used in combining reducers and forming the state tree, it's used by RTK to prefix *that* slice's generated actions. You may want to keep them the same however to make debugging/tracking dispatched actions and state updates a little easier. For example, I even include the slice "name" in the action string of asynchronous actions, e.g. `createAsyncThunk("counter/getCounterFromAPI", ....)`. This is completely subjective though. Use what works well for you and your project's needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... whether or not the name property of a Redux Toolkit slice has to correspond to the property name of the reducer in the configured store.

No, the `name` of the `slice` does not have to match the name of the reducer.

---

The `createSlice` docs mentions this as:

> ##### [name](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createslice#name)
>
> A string name for this slice of state. **Generated action type constants will use this as a prefix.**

The last part is the most important way the name is used. For example, the Redux Dev Tools will the `name` of the slice as prefix for every dispatched action.

---

However, nobody will prevent you from creating a slice like so:

```
export const FooBar = createSlice({
    name: 'okidoki',
    initialState: {
        data: {},
        photo: {}
    },
    reducers: { 
    }
});
```

And then use it in your `store.js` as:

```
import FooBar from './SomeReducerFile.js';

export default createStore(
    combineReducers({
        employee: FooBar
    }),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);
```

Comment: Please use `configureStore` though, not the deprecated `createStore`.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you a brief answer trying not to confuse both terms

name key in slice is basically added as a prefix for action types. lets suppose you name your slice as counter1 then your action types when called will be counter1/actionFunctionUnderReducer

the name you chose in store is what being stored as an objet key. let suppose you assign your reducer a key named counter2, so when using useSelector you will call useSelector(state => state.counter2).

I hope this clarifies the difference between those two.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the same name for both, but in RTK 2.0, `createSlice` has a new [`reducerPath`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#reducerpath) option that will default to `name`.
It also ships with a new [`combineSlices`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/combineSlices) api that will allow you to just inject slices into a new parent slice - which uses that `reducerPath`.

So while it's not necessary, it's a good default and in most cases you probably shouldn't deviate unless you have a reason.